# Hide a specific column in an html table using css

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamic table in which I have an column 'id'. How can I hide that specific column using CSS ? Hiding the n-th td is not an option as the table is dynamic and the column position can change.

Comment: You can use CSS along with Javascript or Jquery to hide that column.

Comment: Post the example HTML markup

Answer (score -1):

If you are using angular you can add a dynamic condition where you can check value of td 
 for example

```
<td *ngIf="data.columnName != ABCD">data.columnName</td>
```